# Are there reasons to use Batch scripts instead of Python to start jenkins builds?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, jenkins

Currently at work windows batch scripts are used to initiate builds (We are primarilly running an inhouse developed exe with some params)

My question is if there is any advantage to using batch script for jenkins instead of let's say a python script? I'm thinking mostly regarding outputs, errors and statuscodes.

I'm much more familiar with python than with batch scripting so i'd like to switch if there aren't any vital importances i'm missing.

I can't find any reasons when googling but i'm very new to jenkins and got little to no clue how it actually works.

Comment: In my experience this is down to the team of developers. Batch scripts are much more widely supported than Python, though internally this might not be an issue. Generally speaking, a Python script should be fine for executing a Jenkins build.

Comment: @JackParkinson I agree with you. Here's some other things. Batch scripts runs all most Windows NT(from `3.0`, we have `command.com`, and `95` and higher, we have `cmd.exe`. And also from `MS-DOS 1.0-7.0`, as long as MS-DOS support those commands(I think it won't).